# How to remove first element in list

Tags: sml, smlnj

I need to remove the first element from a list (the head) and store the value. How would i go about doing that? Im trying to create a stack in sml and making the pop method

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2):

In Standard ML lists are equivalent to stacks. You can use `hd` to get the first element, and you can use `tl` to get the remaining stack. But `hd` and `tl` are partial functions that will fail if the stack is empty. A safer alternative is to use the *'a option* type:

```
fun pop [] = NONE
  | pop (top::stack) = SOME (top, stack)
```

Demonstrating its use:

```
- pop [1,2,3];
> val it = SOME(1, [2, 3]) : (int * int list) option
```

It sounds like you are at a level of learning where a [tutorial](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/standard-ml/) or a [textbook](http://www.it.dtu.dk/introSML/) better suits your needs.

Comment: Good answer, +1, although arguably such a poorly-researched question should be closed.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to remove first element from an array means check below,

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demo">
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="DemoController">
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item}}
      <button data-ng-click="removeItem($index)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input data-ng-model="newItem"><button data-ng-click="addItem(newItem)">Add</button>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Javascript**

```
"use strict";

var demo = angular.module("demo", []);

function DemoController($scope){
$scope.items = [
"potatoes",
"tomatoes",
"flour",
"sugar",
"salt"
 ];

 $scope.addItem = function(item){
 $scope.items.push(item);
 $scope.newItem = null;
 }

 $scope.removeItem = function(index){
 $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
 }
 }
```